# Keyboard shortcut for new class (C#) and new file (typescript)

Tags: c#, typescript, visual-studio

When my context is on or in a folder in Solution Explorer I'd like to be able to hit Ctrl+N and when I'm in a csproj a new class should be made and when I'm in an njsproj a new file should be made (not new item because that still takes lots of clicks to get to the file name textbox).

Is this possible?

Comment: You seem to want to make an extension by yourself, using Control+N on which interface the mouse is hovering over.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT I would like to make this extension but the VSIX templates don't come with any references so they are all broken out of the box unfortunately. Makes it very hard to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using the [Add New File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.AddNewFile) by Mads Kristensen for a while now and it does exactly what I want. `Ctrl+N` from anywhere and the appropriate new file and content is created.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command `Project.AddClass`. Assign a shortcut to it, and there you go. `Ctrl+N` is used for `File.NewFile`, so I would use another one instead.

Or maybe assign `Ctrl+N, F` for `File.NewFile` and `Ctrl+N, C` for `Project.AddClass`.

To select only parts of the VS environment where the shortcut should work use the drop-down list labelled "Use new shortcut in". This way you can use `Ctrl+N` for both commands, depending on context. I don't recommend this for small contexts, such as Solution Explorer, because one may get confused. Big contexts, like various editors (C# editor, JS editor, GUI designer) are fine.

Comment: Currently I do have Ctrl+N mapped to add a new class, what I'd like is to not have multiple shortcuts if possible. The thought process of "ok I'm in C# so I need to press this and I'm in TS so now I press this" for basically the same operation is undesirable.

Comment: @Brad I edited the answer.

Comment: I think that if "JS editor" were an option this could work but unfortunately it is not an option in VS instance.